# SonarQube with Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I have searched and read many post on this but can not find an solution to my particular problem.

When running Sonar on a centos lonux box i get an error:

```
JDBCError: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(10485760) NOT NULL)
```

I have verified that the sonar user (I am using sonarqube) has access to the DB, it is the owner of its own schema and I have granted it all rights to every thing just to make sure its not a permissions thing.

I am using Postgres 9.4.

Full log is as blow, when trying to view the sonar GUI it just displays a page with the following text:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(10485760) NOT NULL) 
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:109:in `create_table'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:371:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:441:in `initialize'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:73:in `automatic_setup'
    from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:272:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094:in `load'
    from file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25:in `load_environment'
    from file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79:in `load_environment'

    at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StatementInvalid) ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(10485760) NOT NULL) 
    at RUBY.log(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227)
    at RUBY.execute(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183)
    at RUBY.create_table(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:109)
    at RUBY.initialize_schema_migrations_table(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:371)
    at RUBY.initialize(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:441)
    at RUBY.up(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401)
    at RUBY.migrate(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383)
    at RUBY.upgrade_and_start(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62)
    at RUBY.automatic_setup(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:73)
    at RUBY.(root)(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:272)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094)
    at RUBY.(root)(file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1)
    at RUBY.load_environment(file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25)
    at RUBY.load_environment(file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79)
```

## FULL LOG

```
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2015.06.11 10:48:26 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process5828587312976552037properties
2015.06.11 10:48:27 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.06.11 10:48:27 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2015.06.11 10:48:27 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434016106548] version[1.4.4], pid[9441], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
2015.06.11 10:48:27 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434016106548] initializing ...
2015.06.11 10:48:27 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1434016106548] loaded [], sites []
2015.06.11 10:48:29 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434016106548] initialized
2015.06.11 10:48:29 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434016106548] starting ...
2015.06.11 10:48:29 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1434016106548] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/10.124.36.4:9001]}
2015.06.11 10:48:29 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1434016106548] sonarqube/FEFMEfLcSuCppleivZ6mEA
2015.06.11 10:48:32 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1434016106548] new_master [sonar-1434016106548][FEFMEfLcSuCppleivZ6mEA][sixdsbox03][inet[/10.124.36.4:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1434016106548}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2015.06.11 10:48:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434016106548] started
2015.06.11 10:48:33 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1434016106548] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
2015.06.11 10:48:34 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2015.06.11 10:48:34 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-28.b13.el6_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process2367145408484339873properties
2015.06.11 10:48:34 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2015.06.11 10:48:35 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: /opt/sonar/web
2015.06.11 10:48:35 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.06.11 10:48:35 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2015.06.11 10:48:36 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1434016106548] loaded [], sites []
2015.06.11 10:48:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2015.06.11 10:48:36 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube
2015.06.11 10:48:37 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /opt/sonar
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Install plugins
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Email notifications / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Core / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Java / 3.0 / 65396a609ddface8b311a6a665aca92a7da694f1
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Git / 1.0 / 9ce9d330c313c296fab051317cc5ad4b26319e07
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin English Pack / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.0 / 213fc8a8b582ff530b12dd4a59a6512be1071234
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_45-b13 [linux-amd64]
2015.06.11 10:48:38 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2015.06.11 10:48:47 INFO  web[jruby.rack] An exception happened during JRuby-Rack startup
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(10485760) NOT NULL)
--- System
jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_45-b13 [linux-amd64]
Time: Thu Jun 11 10:48:47 +0100 2015
Server: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
jruby.home: file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home

--- Context Init Parameters:
jruby.compat.version = 1.8
jruby.max.runtimes = 1
jruby.min.runtimes = 1
jruby.rack.logging = slf4j
process.index = 1
process.key = web
process.sharedDir = /opt/sonar/temp
process.terminationTimeout = 60000
public.root = /
rails.env = production
sonar.cluster.name = sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.driverPath = /opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar
sonar.jdbc.maxActive = 50
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle = 5
sonar.jdbc.maxWait = 5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 600000
sonar.jdbc.minIdle = 2
sonar.jdbc.password = sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 30000
sonar.jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.username = sonarqube
sonar.node.name = sonar-1434016106548
sonar.path.data = /opt/sonar/data
sonar.path.home = /opt/sonar
sonar.path.logs = /opt/sonar/logs
sonar.path.temp = /opt/sonar/temp
sonar.path.web = /opt/sonar/web
sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts =
sonar.search.javaOpts = -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.search.port = 9001
sonar.search.type = TRANSPORT
sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts =
sonar.web.javaOpts = -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

--- Backtrace
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(10485760) NOT NULL)
                                 log at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227
                             execute at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183
                        create_table at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:109
  initialize_schema_migrations_table at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:371
                          initialize at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:441
                                  up at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401
                             migrate at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383
                   upgrade_and_start at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62
                     automatic_setup at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:73
                              (root) at /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:272
                                load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094
                              (root) at file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1
                    load_environment at file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25
                    load_environment at file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79

--- RubyGems
Gem.dir: /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems
Gem.path:
/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems
Activated gems:
  activesupport-2.3.15
  activerecord-2.3.15
  rack-1.1.6
  actionpack-2.3.15
  rails-2.3.15
  color-tools-1.3.0
  i18n-0.4.2
  json-jruby-1.2.3-universal-java-1.6
  activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3
  fastercsv-1.4.0

--- Bundler
undefined method `bundle_path' for Bundler:Module

--- JRuby-Rack Config
compat_version = RUBY1_8
default_logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.StandardOutLogger@238dcac9
equals = <error: >
err = java.io.PrintStream@2ca0e62a
filter_adds_html = true
filter_verifies_resource = false
ignore_environment = false
initial_memory_buffer_size =
initial_runtimes = 1
jms_connection_factory =
jms_jndi_properties =
logger = org.jruby.rack.logging.Slf4jLogger@64935b57
logger_class_name = slf4j
logger_name = jruby.rack
maximum_memory_buffer_size =
maximum_runtimes = 1
num_initializer_threads =
out = java.io.PrintStream@4a8c212
rackup =
rackup_path =
rewindable = true
runtime_arguments =
runtime_environment =
runtime_timeout_seconds =
serial_initialization = false
servlet_context = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@2eaa81c7
throw_init_exception = false

2015.06.11 10:48:47 ERROR web[jruby.rack] initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(10485760) NOT NULL)
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:109:in `create_table'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:371:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:441:in `initialize'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:73:in `automatic_setup'
        from /opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:272:in `(root)'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094:in `load'
        from file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1:in `(root)'
        from file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25:in `load_environment'
        from file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79:in `load_environment'

        at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StatementInvalid) ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(10485760) NOT NULL)
        at RUBY.log(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.execute(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.create_table(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:109) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.initialize_schema_migrations_table(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:371) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.initialize(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:441) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.up(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.migrate(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.upgrade_and_start(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:62) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.automatic_setup(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:73) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.(root)(/opt/sonar/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:272) ~[na:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.load_environment(file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25) ~[na:na]
        at RUBY.load_environment(file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79) ~[na:na]
2015.06.11 10:48:47 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.06.11 10:48:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2015.06.11 10:48:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2015.06.11 10:48:47 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
```

Comment: It seems that the schema "public" is not available at jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the DB has not been setup correctly to work with Sonar.

sonar.jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.username = sonarqube

Since you're using PostgresSQL I would point you to the following GIST: https://gist.github.com/RawToast/feab6b36d2592554d071

Just change the user and DB references in the Gist from 'sonar' to 'sonarqube' and add a password to sonar.properties under sonar.jdbc.username (e.g. sonar.jdbc.password = sonarqube)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is too late to response to this, but I recently ran into similar error and it took me a while to debug the problem.

The problem in my case was misunderstanding what needs to be done as you need to have user with password to be set (Sonarqube properties) and configure (in Postgresql DB)

```
sonar.jdbc.username=<sonar_user>
sonar.jdbc.password=<sonar_user_password>
```

Then the connection string must be correct

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<sonar_postgres_db>
```

And then you need to have schema configured and the  must have it set as search_path (I still don't understand all that, so apologies for terminology)

So as @RawToast answer did help me, but I had to do the following:

- create schema sonardb (exactly what Sonarqube was expecting)
- set search path for  to point to that schema `ALTER USER <sonar_user> SET search_path TO sonardb;`

ALTER USER sonar SET search_path TO sonardb;